# Book about an experimental flying boat, 1930s?

Tags: story-identification, books

As a child in the '60s I read an action book belonging to my father.

The story centred around an experimental and secret privately developed flying boat - literally a ship that looked like a tramp steamer but was built out of a revolutionary light metal and with internal gas reservoirs (using a special gas) that allowed it to fly like a dirigible and was an armed merchantman.

The plot included an antagonist, a slightly inferior, but more heavily armed version made from stolen plans by an unfriendly power that was hunting it.   From memory, the story included a plucky cabin boy....

Comment: Too recent, but https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/428042.Airborn

Comment: Thanks, yes, too recent. The original story is set in then contemporary times rather than an alternate world and the flying ship is a new if secret development.

Comment: There's a book by Percy Westerman called [The Flying Submarine](https://www.fadedpage.com/showbook.php?pid=201410K3) that is similar. The gas that makes the submarine fly is called *helia*. But it's a submarine not a boat and there is no plucky cabin boy.